# Google Maps location of Large Bell (Ōgane + Daishōrō) of Chion-in temple in Kyoto

Tags: japan, locate-this, kyoto

I'd like to know if I have the Google Maps location of the [Large Bell in Chion-in](http://www.chion-in.or.jp/e/place_to_see/buildings2.html) temple in Kyoto wrong, or if it's temporarily closed as of this writing (April 2018).

[image: Large Bell (Ōgane + Daishōrō) of Chion-in temple in Kyoto]

I visited this bell before by chance around 2015, but I'm having issues locating it on Google Maps. I thought I had found it [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Japan,+%E3%80%92605-0062+Ky%C5%8Dto-fu,+Ky%C5%8Dto-shi,+Higashiyama-ku,+Rinkach%C5%8D,+%E5%A4%A7%E9%90%98%E6%A5%BC/@35.0062868,135.783842,19.82z/data=!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x600108dc414283b9:0x609373abd0eaf97c!2sChion-in!8m2!3d35.0054141!4d135.7823785!3m4!1s0x600108db93719159:0x5a514e6d0f8752ce!8m2!3d35.0042428!4d135.7839795), but recently access to it (during opening hours) wasn't possible. All access paths seem to be blocked. (At least 4-5 other groups of frustrated tourists seemed to be trying to access it from a few different places visible on the map, to no avail.) Perhaps the blocks are temporary and the bell is indeed in that location?

Answer (score 2):

The location appears correct since it matches [the official map](http://www.chion-in.or.jp/04_meiho/map.html), where it's #8 大鐘楼.  (Note that you need to rotate the 3D-ish official map clockwise around 45 degrees to get it line up.)

Per the temple website, [the Miei-do hall is under major construction](http://www.chion-in.or.jp/13_mieido_daishuri/index.html) and won't fully reopen until 2019.  However, there is no mention of any work involving the bell tower.